# Remove Duplicates from a list of namedtuples

Tags: python, tuples

I often gets confused with list and tuples due to my Javascript background, so please excuse me.

I have a list of namedtuples something like this:

```
[AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='cde', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='efg', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='hij', is_admin=True), AdminInfo(username='jkl', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='xyz', is_admin=False)]
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates from here. For simple list, I can do

```
a = list(set(<var>))
```

But in this case, it seems we can't convert to set. If I try, it fails with error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'AdminInfo'
```

Can anyone please help me removing duplicates from above list.

Comment: Are you sure `AdminInfo` is a named tuple, and not your own class without a `__hash__()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the names from each class an check if a list of the checked already contains it.

```
class AdminInfo:
    name = None

    def is_admin(self):
        return self.val_is_admin

    def __init__(self, username='Undefined', is_admin=False):
        self.val_is_admin = is_admin
        self.name = username

ai_list = [AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='cde', is_admin=False),
           AdminInfo(username='efg', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='hij', is_admin=True),
           AdminInfo(username='jkl', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False),
           AdminInfo(username='xyz', is_admin=False)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = []
    n_list = []
    for i in ai_list:
        if i.name not in names:
            names.append(i.name)
            n_list.append(i)
    print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the snippet you need:

```
import numpy
class AdminInfo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        [setattr(self, key, kwargs[key]) for key in kwargs]

def remove_duplicated(l):
    numpy.array(l)[numpy.unique(numpy.array([user.username for user in l]), return_index=True)[1]].tolist()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_list = [
        AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), 
        AdminInfo(username='cde', is_admin=False), 
        AdminInfo(username='efg', is_admin=False), 
        AdminInfo(username='hij', is_admin=True), 
        AdminInfo(username='jkl', is_admin=False), 
        AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), 
        AdminInfo(username='xyz', is_admin=False)
    ]
    final_list = remove_duplicated(start_list)
        
    assert len(start_list) == len(final_list) + 1
    assert [user.username for user in start_list].count("abc") == 2
    assert [user.username for user in final_list].count("abc") == 1
```

Using numpy arrays, this solution is much more adapted for large amont of datas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused because you want a list of unique AdminInfo *objects*, based on the value of the username *property*. In your code, you have created a list of eight unique AdminInfo objects, two of which share the same name.

This code should give you what I think you're looking for. It will return a list of the last instance of each AdminInfo object with a given username. It exploits the fact that if you add a duplicate key to a dictionary, the new value will overwrite the old value.

```
ai_list = [AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='cde', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='efg', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='hij', is_admin=True), AdminInfo(username='jkl', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='abc', is_admin=False), AdminInfo(username='xyz', is_admin=False)]
ai_dict = dict((item.name, item) for item in ai_list)
ai_list = list(ai_dict.values())
```